# Uk citizen working freelance for companies worldwide. Who do I pay tax to?

Tags: united-states, taxes, united-kingdom

I'm a designer from the uk who works from home in the uk for companies here & overseas, namely the US. I've worked for a few years to these companies never with any problems, but have now been asked for a social security or EIN number to get my invoiced paid from one, which obviously I don't have. Is there anything else I can provide them with or do?

I've always invoiced US / Canadian / French individuals and companies as normal and paid my tax here. Is there something differently I should be doing, in particular to work for the US?

Thanks!

Comment: My guess is, and it's just a guess, that you need an EIN otherwise your clients will have to pay [withholding tax out of your fee.](https://sa.www4.irs.gov/modiein/individual/help/keyword.jsp?question=Do%20I%20need%20an%20EIN%3F)

Comment: @PeterK. only if the income is subject to withholding.

Answer (score 1):

You can get an [ITIN](http://www.irs.gov/Individuals/Individual-Taxpayer-Identification-Number-%28ITIN%29) if you qualify, and use it. If you need to file tax returns in the US (including claiming refunds of withholding) - you can get an ITIN.

Otherwise - you don't have to provide them EIN/SSN/ITIN, since as a foreigner you cannot have those. You still need to provide them a W8 form to certify that you are indeed a foreigner. Talk to your accountant about it.